# Using a Background video with a colour overlay with 100% height

Tags: html, css

I am trying add a background video that has a colour overlay with a transparency.

I have set up the website structure already, with each Div section with a height of 100% and a background colour. The first div section I want to play a video that is visible through the transparent background colour.

I two problems I face is each the video takes over the website or it pushes the content down.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NpgD5/248/

My html currently looks like this:

```
 <div class="top-section">
   <div id="bg"><video src="" id="bg-video" muted autoplay loop ></video></div>
    <nav> </nav>      
   <div id="center-column">
     <h1>WELCOME</h1>
   </div>
  <div class="mid1-section"></div>
  <div class="mid2-section"></div>
  <div class="bottom-section"></div>
 </div>
```

CSS :

```
html, body{
  background-color: #ECF0F1;
  min-height:100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


#bg {
position: fixed;
top: -50%;
left: -50%;
width: 200%;
height: 100%;
}


/*HTML5 VIDEO*/
#bg video {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 50%;
}

.top-section{
background-color: #3498DB;
background-repeat: repeat;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
z-index: 2;
}

.mid1-section{
  min-height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #16A085;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

Any feedback is appreciated thank you (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the div and style the video individually

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice the color overlay part.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the video to be the background for the page itself.

If that's the case, you should try to make 2 main elements with different z-indexes. One being the video for the bg and a wrapper for your content.

A visual representation of the layout you're trying to achieve would really help for a better answer.